# What is the oracle database 12c IP Address

Tags: oracle

I just Installed Oracle Database 12c. At the end of the installation it gave me Information about my connection. SID, IP, etc. I restarted the computer run all these services (some of them already running):

- OracleJobSchedulerORCL
- OracleOraDB12Home1MTSRecoveryService
- OracleOraDB12Home1TNSListener
- OracleRemExecServiceV2
- OracleServiceORCL
- OracleVssWriterORCL

But I think I forgot the IP and port of my database since I tried to access the database using a webbrowser and it doesn't work (I tried `https://10.10.10.10:5500/em`). I don't know If the problem is really the IP:Port that I may have forgotten or if I forgot to run service. I am pretty sure the IP address look like `https://10.10.x.x:xxxx/em` but I don't I am not certain. Is there a way to recover the IP address and port of the database?

**EDIT:** I've installed it on Windows 8 x64 JP. with
In Environment Variable

- with ORACLE_HOSTNAME = 10.10.10.10
- ORACLE_UNQNAME = orcl

And in the **host** file (in System32/Drivers/etc/)

- 127.0.0.1       localhost
- 10.10.10.10          wopr.orcl           wopr

Answer (score 2):

Per documentation, format for accessing enterprise manager in your browser

```
http://hostname:portnumber/em
```

Once you sure that default port number is kept as default HTTP port number is `5500` then you can get your system hostname. Port numbers are recorded in `$ORACLE_HOME/install/portlist.ini file`.

If running windows then just run the command `hostname` which will give you the hostname of your machine. Then run like

```
 http://My_hostname:5500/em
```

Or use the command `ipconfig` to see your IPV4 address and use that address

```
 http://X.X.X.X:5500/em
```

Or you as well use `localhost`

```
 http://localhost:5500/em
```

or `127.0.0.1` (loop back address) like

```
 http://127.0.0.1:5500/em
```

[See here for more information](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B16276_01/doc/server.102/b14196/em_manage003.htm)

Comment: my '$ORACLE_HOME/install/portlist.ini' file is empty/blank my hostname is WOPR and I tried my ipv4 LAN address given by ipconfig it doesn't work. localhost, 127.0.0.1, and 10.10.10.10 (address that figures in my hosts file) don't work either.

Comment: @PaikuHan, are you sure you had a successful installation? I doubt though. As in other answer you commented that, you have installed "EM". Would it be that hard ... if you try to reinstall .. just a suggestion.

Comment: Is your enterprise manager running at all (which would named as `Oracle<agent_home>Agent`)? check once. I think you should go through this doc once http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24628_01/doc.121/e24473/emctl.htm

Comment: I don't have anything like that in my services. Should I check somewhere else?

Comment: `start -> run -> services` ... check there if you have this service. you can as well use `emctl` command to check the status of the service. If that service is not listed then I doubt you have installed enterprise manager at all. Go through that link in my other comment .. you will understand. It has mentioned all the steps in detail.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you installed it on your local machine, you can always access it using `localhost`, so try `https://localhost:5500/em`.

The default port number for Enterprise Manager is indeed `5500`.

Comment: yes I'm sure it was the 6GB one right? the other were like 2-4GB

Comment: Enterprise manager is a feature you can enable/disable on installation on all versions.

Comment: Yes I know I mean when I was installing I was asked which version I wanted and I chose the default one that took the most space (6GB) the others were: Standard Edition (5.5GB), Standard Edition One(5.5GB) and  Personal Edition (3.53GB). But I can always check if you tell me how to do it.

Comment: Even with SEO you have Enterprise Manager.

Comment: So the problem doesn't seem to come from there?

Comment: Not the version installed. Maybe the options selected?